# Elasticsearch aggregate field between dates

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to compare two buckets against each other and find new occurrences that appear in the second bucket.  The below query returns all entries in the "query.keyword" field between the two UNIX timestamps provided but I want the UNIX timestamps to be apart of the aggregation section itself.

```
GET _search
    {
      "size": 0,
      "query": {
        "range" :{
          "ts": {
            "gte":1535155200,
            "lte":1535414399
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "domains": {
          "terms": {
            "field":"query.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I've also tried this but received the error:

```
"Found two aggregation type definitions in [domains_prev]: [range] and [terms]",

GET _search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "domains_prev": {
      "range" :{
        "field":"ts",
        "ranges": [
          {"to" :  1535414399},
          {"from" : 1535155200}
        ]
      },
      "terms": {
        "field":"query.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The goal is to have something similar to this:

```
Agg1
"domains_prev"
"field":"query.keyword"
date:gte:timestamp, lte:timestamp

Agg2
"domains_today"
"field":"query.keyword"
date:today

show all "query.keyword" in agg2 that does not appear in agg1.
```

This is the SQL query that I use to achieve the intended result:

```
select domains FROM table WHERE date >= 20171123 and domains NOT IN (SELECT domains FROM table WHERE date < 20171123 group by domains)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do a nested bucket aggregation starting with date range:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-daterange-aggregation.html

From their page, start with an aggregation like this at the top level:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "range": {
            "date_range": {
                "field": "date",
                "format": "MM-yyy",
                "ranges": [
                    { "to": "now-10M/M" }, 
                    { "from": "now-10M/M" } 
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then nest your existing terms aggregation using query.keyword under that.

The end result should be something like:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "range": {
            "date_range": {
                "field": "date",
                "format": "MM-yyy",
                "ranges": [
                    { "to": "now-10M/M" }, 
                    { "from": "now-10M/M" } 
                ]
            },
            "aggs": {
                "domains": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field":"query.keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```